# SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'xxxx' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools

I have got error on IE8 for undefined , not a function object.
But on IE10 and other browsers it works fine. Below is Javascript code

```
 function SendInterestLoudAndClear1(e, link, username, profileLink, listingStatus) {
        // disable further clicks
        if($(e) != null){
            $(e).set("onclick", "SendInterestLoudAndClear(null)");

      if (link.indexOf("sendinterest") > -1) {
          // Only need the listingStatus
          SetListingDetails('', listingStatus);

          if ('{{listingtype}}' == 'look') {
             DoTracking( 'LoggedInSummaryLook','click', 'SendInterestButton', listingStatus);
          }
          else {
               DoTracking( 'LoggedInSummaryHave', 'click','SendInterestButton', listingStatus);
          }
          new Request({
              url: link,
              onSuccess: function () {
                {%if useLoudandClear %}


                    var lightboxId = 'send_interest-basic';
                    if ({{subsStatus}} == false || listingStatus == '2')
                    {
                        lightboxId = 'send_interest-premium';
                    }
                     SetLightBoxForSendInterest(lightboxId, username, profileLink);
                     showLightBox(lightboxId, 659);



                      if (e.getAttribute('title') == null || e.getAttribute('title') == "") {
                          // Remove this node but get a reference to its parent
                          var parent = $(e).getParent(); 
                          // Destroy the anchor link and child - free memory.
                          $(e).destroy();

                          // Construct new html to be inserted into parent node
                          var img1 = new Element("img", { src: "{{StaticURL}}/images/ok.png", alt: "{{caption3108}}" });
                          var span2 = new Element("span", { class: "erm-grey-fav", title: "{{caption3108}}", text: "{{caption3108}}", onclick: "SendInterestLoudAndClear(this)" });
                          var interestSentElements = new Elements([img1, span2]);

                          // Use adopt instead to add to dom new divs
                          $(parent).adopt(interestSentElements);
                      }
                  {%else%}
                        //showLightBox('interestsentbox', 300);
                      if (e.getAttribute('title') == null || e.getAttribute('title') == "") {
                          e.removeAttribute('onclick');
                          e.removeAttribute('style');
                          // e.innerHTML='{{caption1393}}';
                          $(e).set("html", '{{caption1393}}');
                          var id1 = e.get('id');
                          var img1 = id1 + "_sendinterest";
                          $(img1).src = "{{StaticURL}}/images/ok.png";
                          $(img1).style.display = "inline";
                          e.setAttribute('title', "{{caption1269}}");
                          e.set('class', 'erm-grey-fav');
                      }
              {%endif%}
              },
              onFailure: function () {
                  alert("failed");
              }
          }).send();
      }
      }

  }
```

Comment: That's a bunch of code.  Exactly where do you get that error?  (You should be able to tell with the developer console.)

Comment: Also `$(anything)` will **never** be `null`. - *edit* wait; what library is that?  It doesn't really look like jQuery, or if it is, it's some kind of really bizarre jQuery code.

Comment: @Pointy I do not think it is jQuery.... Looks like some other library using the `$` variable maybe?

Comment: its not Prototype either

Comment: I'm think it's MooTools - `$` is an alias for `document.getElementById`, and seems to have the methods the OP is using: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element

Comment: can you post more code or make a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: > `$ is an alias for document.getElementById` - not really. it's an alias for `document.id`, which in IE6/7/8 extends the element to get the proto methods it does not have from Element.prototype. this code is a mix of vanilla.js and mootools and is not safe at best. the point of using a library is to abstract the api for dom access so it is cross browser, not monkey patch as you deem fit.

Comment: @Pointy, Sergio, -- that issue was resolved it was occured due to some syntax problem but now for next method in JS file it gives that error.  It seems for IE8 any syntax we need to consider.

Comment: @user2596146, if the question was solved please delete the question or post the answer here. If you still have a problem please post more info so we can help.

Comment: Check your script tag, may be you forget to put `type="text/javascript"`. Script tag should be like this `<script type="text/javascript">`